# Sphinx - how do I use the Extended query syntax with the PHP API

Tags: php, api, full-text-search, sphinx

Can anyone explain how I would make Sphinx do phrase matching with the Extended query syntax - here is my code..

```
    $cl = new SphinxClient();
    $cl->SetServer($CONF['sphinx_host'], $CONF['sphinx_port']);
    $cl->SetSortMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
    $cl->SetFieldWeights ( array ( "title" => 100, "description" => 90 ) );
    $cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
    $cl->SetRankingMode(SPH_RANK_SPH04);
    $cl->SetLimits(0, 1000);

    $q = 'She sells sea shells';
    $result = $cl->Query($q);
```

How would I perform phrase matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $q = '"She sells sea shells"';
```

Just put the query in quotes (or just part of the query!)

```
 $q = '"She sells" sea shells';
```